# Group/throttle burst of events with AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs, throttling

I'm working on an event-based email notification service. An email is sent on every single event at the moment. The problem with this approach is sometimes there are too many events for a short period of time, thus the user gets too many emails at once. Instead of this, I'd like to throttle and group these emails by user.

I'm looking at AWS SQS to pipe these events into it and somehow consume them with a lambda that picks and groups the ones ready (ready=been there for at least 3 minutes) to be sent. Is there a built-in solution? Can I tag events with user ID and on the consumer side I pick the latest one, check if it's been there for 3 minutes, if so I pick all the remaining ones...? Just and idea...

Comment: what do you mean by 'pick all the remaining ones"? when a message is there at least for 3 minutes for a specific user/email, then, you want to receive all his messages from the queue? you can set  configure so-called delay queue which can postpone the delivery of new messages to a queue for a number of seconds, e.g. 3 minutes.

Comment: Let's say a new message arrived with a specific user ID. Before processing it, there is a 3 minutes time interval to see if more messages with the same user ID come. All the additional messages within this interval should be sent in 1 single email. I don't really get why would delaying help me here?